# How to check a line in file for any key in a dictionary and then use that key to get information from dictionary, in one for loop

Tags: python, regex, file, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to set up a method to take a dictionary and check each line in a file for one of the keys.  If the key exists, then print the value from the dictionary.

This is what I have so far:

```
info = {'#check here 1':{'action':'read'}, '#check here 2':{'action':'delete'}}

with open(input_file_name, "r") as old_file, open(output_file_name, "w") as new_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
            x = [k in line.strip() for k in info]
            if any(x):
                print("found key")
                print(x)
                print()
```

And this prints:

```
found key
[True, False]

found key
[False, True]
```

Normally, what I would do is a nested for loop, where for each line in the file, I loop through the dictionary to check if any key is present.  However, I was told that doing this in one for loop going through each line of the file would be more resource effective.  Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Edit:  Also, here is the structure of the file:

```
hello world #check here 1
how are you #check here 1

#check here 2
```

I'm currently trying to see if I can setup a regex to match for this instead. If I can do that, then I'll set the match as a variable and use that variable to search the dictionary:

```
comment = re.compile(r'#.+')

for line in lines:
    print(comment.match(line)
```

However, this is only matching `#check here 2`, and not `#check here 1`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this with regex:

```
search_pattern = re.compile(r'.*(#.+)')

with open(input_file_name, "r") as old_file, open(output_file_name, "w") as new_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        edit_point = search_pattern.match(line)
        if edit_point:
            result = edit_point.group(1)
            if result in edit_info:
                print(line)
```